# PhpMyAdmin. Вопросы вместо русских букв

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, php7, xampp

У меня в phpMyAdmin вместо русских букв в таблице отображаются знаки вопроса. Я понимаю, что это проблемы с кодировкой, но не могу перекодировать уже готовую таблицу, чтобы она отображалась правильно. Подскажите, пожалуйста: что надо делать? Удалить старую базу и переписать заново её с нормальной кодировкой (у меня нормальная - utf8), к сожалению, невозможно, так как база состоит предположительно из десятков таблиц с сотнями строк. Спасибо за ответы.

Ход моей работы:

1. Запущены все три службы ХАМРР (у меня ХАМРР 7.0.8).
2. В терминале Линукса ввожу следующие пять команд:

   sudo mysql -S '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock'

   create database zveri;

   use zveri;

   create user 'z1'@'localhost' identified by '12345';

   grant all privileges on zveri.* to 'z1'@'localhost';
3. Далее там же, в терминале, создаю таблицу и вставляю туда данные:

   source /opt/lampp/htdocs/CodeSamplesRus/createtable.sql;

   source /opt/lampp/htdocs/CodeSamplesRus/insertintotable.sql;

Терминал выдаёт сообщение о каких-то предупреждениях, которые не знаю, как прочитать:

*Database changed
Query OK, 5 rows affected, 10 warnings (0.03 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 10*

Файлы созданы с кодировкой UTF-8 в ActiveState Komodo Edit 11.

**createtable:**

```
CREATE TABLE Information
( Nomer INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Odin CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Dva CHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

**insertintotable:**

```
USE zveri;
INSERT INTO Information VALUES
  (NULL, 'Раз', 'Вышел'),
  (NULL, 'Два', 'Зайчик'),
  (NULL, 'Три', 'Погулять'),
  (NULL, 'Четыре', 'На полянке'),
  (NULL, 'Пять', 'Поскакать');
```

В результате в таблице в phpMyAdmin отображается информация, показанная на скриншоте.

Интересно, что если зайти во вкладку Structure для таблицы Information, то Collation там будет равно latin1_swedish_ci. При чём тут шведская кодировка - совершенно неясно, но ладно. :)

4. Пытаюсь перекодировать в Терминале. Сначала всю базу:

   alter database zveri character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;

   show create table Information;

Показывает:

*ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1*

Ничего не получилось.

5. Затем пытаюсь перекодировать только таблицу, хоть это не совсем, по-моему, хороший способ (а если таблиц много - возиться с каждой по отдельности?)

   alter table Information convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;

   show create table Information;

Показывает:

*ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci*

В Терминале перекодировал. И во вкладке Structure тоже перекодировал. Однако в phpMyAdmin в самой таблице вместо данных русскими буквами всё равно остаются вопросы без изменений.

Как это исправить?

[image: вид в phpMyAdmin]

Comment: Перезалить данные после шага 5, и будут у вас нормально отображаться русские символы.

Comment: А перезалить данные - это как? Это ввести в таблицу данные по новой? Я верно понимаю?А если таблиц много? Чтобы мне научиться это делать для любых ситуаций.

Comment: Вы всегда можете снять бэкап данных, изменить кодировку, и залить данные наместо в нужной кодировке.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на ваш 5й шаг. Вы сделали перекодировку таблицы. Теперь она готова для загрузки данных. Удалите старые данные (которые ????) и залейте по новой их в таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо! Это сработало. А нельзя делать такое без перезалития данных? Вот, например, если база состоит из многих таблиц. Я задался вопросом: предположим, в практической деятельности мне дадут базу для работы, состоящую из многих таблиц и строк. Я её открою, а там будет неправильная кодировка. Смогу ли я эту кодировку поменять в условиях, когда переписать данные по новой представляет большой труд? И если смогу, то как это сделать? Или этот мой вопрос, о котором я задумался, в реальной практике никогда не возникает? Я не знаю.